# Applying an implication from a hypothesis

Tags: coq

My coq proof currently looks like this:

```
a0 : nat
a1 : nat
n : nat
l : list nat
c : nat -> nat -> bool
H : forall a0 a1 a2 : nat,
    Is_true (c a0 a1) /\ Is_true (c a1 a2) -> Is_true (c a0 a2)
H0 : Is_true (c a1 a0)
H1 : Is_true (c a0 n)
============================
 Is_true (c a1 n)
```

How can I 'apply' H and finish the proof?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
apply (H _ _ _ (conj H0 H1)).
```

Or:

```
exact (H _ _ _ (conj H0 H1)).
```

But that would be similar to doing:

```
apply H; assumption.
```

Or anything similar. I am not sure what the point of your question is exactly. Did I miss a detail?